# Echoing an abstract variable in PHP

Tags: php, string, variables, echo

So I have some code that looks like this

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <?php echo "text_". $textnum ?>
 </td>
</tr>
```

And I want the code to function the same as

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <?php echo $text_x ?>
 </td>
</tr>
```

Where X is the value of $textnum. I cannot just use `<?php echo $text_1 ?>` because I dont know which text variable i am going to be echoing

Answer (score 0):

Use `<?=${'text_'.$textnum};?>` or `<?php echo ${'text_'.$textnum} ?>`